# Liquibase beginner: making a ManyToMany association bidirectional

Tags: mysql, migration, liquibase

I am using Hibernate with JPA annotations. I have a one-directional many-to-many association that I intend to make bi-directional.

The database already contains some data. I'm thinking of using Liquibase to do the tables' update. Can someone give me some insight as to the type of changelog I have to write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting unidirectional many-to-many relationship to bidirectional doesn't require any database schema changes. You only need to change your classes and their mapping.

Comment: Seriously? I thought an additional table was used. Oh well, silly me! Thanks!

Comment: @Panayiotis: Join table is the same in both cases.